# Inference rules demonstrate that is true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following propositions and statement

\begin{align}
1. &  &q \to  \neg p\\
2. & &p\vee s\\
3. && \neg q \to \neg r\\
4. && r\\
\therefore &&s
\end{align}

I need to demonstrate that is true.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is line two supposed to be $q\vee s$?

Comment: it's p v s. The statement might be false. Maybe I didn't mention that.

Comment: What you refer to as a 'statement' is called an *argument*.  And the argument is not 'false', but *invalid*.

Comment: @Shaun How did you make text a link in Comments, like you just did?  I've searched a good bit but never figured that out ...

Comment: @Bram28, you do this: `[text](link)`.

Comment: @Shaun Great, that worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $1$-$4$ are premisses. Then it's not necessarily that $s$ is true. It may be that $p$ and $r$ are true and $q$ and $s$ are false.

In fact what we can say about the statements is that $p$ and $r$ are true, but $q$ is false. We already know that $r$ is true and the third premiss can be rewritten as $r\rightarrow p$ so we also know $p$ to be true. And the first can be rewritten as $p\rightarrow \neg q$ so we know $q$ to be false.

The only one that involves $s$ is the second, but since $p$ is true there's no restriction on $s$.

(If the third should be interpreted as $\neg (p\rightarrow\neg r)$ it would require $p$ to be true yet $r$ false which contradicts the fourth - then you could by RAA prove $s$ of course).

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as a 'statement' is called an *argument*.  And the argument is not 'false', but *invalid*.

To demonstrate this, all you need to do is to provide a simple counterexample: a scenario where the premises are true and the conclusion is false.

In this case, when we set $r$ and $p$ to true, and $q$ and $s$ to false, the premises will come out true, but the conclusion is false.